# Downloading n number of html files which shows geospatial maps (hazard maps)

Tags: javascript, next.js, download, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a nextjs application which let's users upload an excel file with a list of addresses.

The application then shows a hazard map per each address. Further, the user can then download each hazard map as an html file.

The problem I'm running into at the moment is that when I have around 50+ addresses in the excel file, the download logic seems to fail, and by that I mean the screen just goes to `Aw, Snap. Something went wrong`.

I created a route handler (api route) to create and return the html template (the template of course contains a script tag for the necessary javascript to show the hazard maps via leaflet).

```js
// the route handler:

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  if (!request.body) return NextResponse.json({ status: 400 });

  const requestBody: LeafletData = await request.json();

  // consider minifying?
  const htmlTemplate = leafletTemplate(
    requestBody.address,
    requestBody.coords,
    requestBody.coastlines,
    requestBody.faultLines,
    requestBody.snowfall,
    requestBody.snowfallAreas,
    requestBody.volcanoes,
    requestBody.geoJson,
    requestBody.tileLayers
  );

  return NextResponse.json({
    status: 200,
    template: htmlTemplate,
  });
}


// fetching and downloading as a zip
for (const [index, fileItem] of selectedFile.fileContent.entries()) {
  const leafletData = leaflet[index];
  const coords = { lat: fileItem.lat, lng: fileItem.lng };
  const { type, features } = leafletData[fileItem.addr];

  // this endpoint returns the html template
  const response = await fetch("/leaflet/api", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    address: fileItem.addr,
    coords,
    coastlines,
    faultLines,
    snowfall,
    snowfallAreas,
    volcanoes,
    geoJson: { type, features },
    tileLayers: leafletData[fileItem.addr],
    }),
  });

  const { template } = await response.json();

  zip.file(`${fileItem.id}_${fileItem.addr}.html`, template);
}

zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then((content) => {
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(content);
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url;
  a.download = `${selectedFile.filename}_result.zip`;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
```

Would minifying help? How much can I save by removing whitespace? since it is geospatial data, some html files can be over well over 10MB.

I could limit how many files a user can download (perhaps only download selected), but I think they'll want to be able to download them all at once.

Any ideas/tips/advice?

Comment: Is there any actual useful information in the developer tools console, since `Aw, Snap. Something went wrong` is completely useless (not your fault - Chrome is garbage) ... if not, try a different browser to see if you can get some insight into what the problem actually is

Comment: and to clarify, when you say "n number of html files" ... you mean the 50+ you mention in the question? Perhaps download one after the other (or 10 at a time or something other than 50+ at once)

Comment: Perhaps the error in the console could be of use:
`Error: aborted
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:787:14)
    at abortIncoming (node:_http_server:793:17)
    at socketOnClose (node:_http_server:787:3)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:35)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:337:12)
    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'`
Otherwise, on safari it says: webpage reloaded due to significant memory usage

Comment: I believe the cause is in the loop and adding the files in the zip.file per each address?
And I could just have it download every x amount in a new zip (20 html file per zip?), but I would like to know if I could do it by downloading it as 1 zip (since that's what the users asked for).

Comment: Seems like they are fine with downloading in batches. Currently set to 20 addresses in 1 zip file. Will update if it is okay